# Is it possible to set the default Google Docs styles for all users in an organisation?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

Most people in our 60+ organisation have the default Arial/Helvetica heading styles. However, a number of people seem to have quite different Trebuchet headings. These people haven't explicitly changed their styles.

Is there a way of globally managing the default styles for all users in an organisation so I can do away with this Trebuchet oddness once and for all?

Answer (score 8):

The only way I have found to do this is to do the following:

1. Create a generic document that contains all your styles
2. Save that document as a template
3. Get each user in your organisation to open that document from the template library
4. With the document open they need to click on the styles field, then options, then save as my default styles

I wish there was a better way that you could apply this globally as an admin :-|